# The for loop doesn't loop even when the answer is not right

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, while-loop

> **The problem may be somewhere in the end,the for loop stops and the input is asked**

````
while enter!="off":
    if enter == "1":
        prefer= input("enter your preference")
        if prefer =="sports":
            print("Hardcore Sports Podcast")
            enter = input('Enter 1 - recommendation, 2 - draw, off - exit')
        else:
            print("Kanye West's new album")
            enter = input('Enter 1 - recommendation, 2 - draw, off - exit')
    if enter=="2":
        band=input("Enter the name of the band")
        for word in range(3):
            if band=="Queen":
                print("You win a concert ticket!")
                break
    enter = input('Enter 1 - recommendation, 2 - draw, off - exit')  ```
````

Comment: do you have 'enter' declared before the while loop?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `range(3)` loop? You think that if the first time `band` is not equal to `Queen` it might be the second time?

Comment: I don't really understand the questions in the program. What is the expected behaviour and what do you get instead?

Comment: You have `enter = input('Enter 1 - recommendation, 2 - draw, off - exit')` too many times. Just have the one at the end. Or maybe move that to the very begining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop actually does loop, it just does do anything unless the answer is correct. you want:

```
while enter!="off":
    if enter == "1":
        prefer= input("enter your preference")
        if prefer =="sports":
            print("Hardcore Sports Podcast")
            enter = input('Enter 1 - recommendation, 2 - draw, off - exit')
        else:
            print("Kanye West's new album")
            enter = input('Enter 1 - recommendation, 2 - draw, off - exit')
    if enter=="2":
        for word in range(3): #swapped this line
            band=input("Enter the name of the band") #with this line
            if band=="Queen":
                print("You win a concert ticket!")
                break

    enter = input('Enter 1 - recommendation, 2 - draw, off - exit')
```

Just swap line 11 with line 12 so that the input call is in the loop.

I think a slight improvement would be to use:

```
while enter!="off":
    if enter == "1":
        prefer= input("enter your preference")
        print("Hardcore Sports Podcast") if prefer =="sports" else print("Kanye West's new album")
    if enter=="2":
        for _ in range(3):
            band = input("Enter the name of the band")
            if band == "Queen":
                print("You win a concert ticket!")
                break
    enter = input('Enter 1 - recommendation, 2 - draw, off - exit')
```

Comment: thank you @EliHarold

Comment: @MarioGjonaj no problem